# Angular 2 - Different template at same url level

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

There is a way to use a different template in pages mapped with the same url level on angular 2, for example:

- host/login
- host/dashboard

Now in my app template I put both templates and change them using *ngIf, but I think this is not the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

I resolve the problem modifying the routes, I post the solution because I found a lot of people looking for this, but I cant found the solution.

This is how I configure the routes:

```
    const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {path: 'login', component: LoginPage},
    {
        path: '', component: DashboardPage, children: [
        {path: 'general', component: GeneralInfoPage},
        {path: 'other', component: OtherPage}
    ]
    }
];
```

Where DashboardPage is the template for the app (with menu, and other stuff) and LoginPage is a clean template without that.

Comment: Just a quick note: you have to add an additional <router-outlet> to the DashboardPage component...